# paypal parallel payment 550001 error User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

i integrated paypal parallel payment In sandbox environment (Language:php)  and it works fine
but when i go live , it will give me error "550001 User is not allowed to perform this action" how come i get over from this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a couple of points you may want to double check:

- Make sure your account is Premier/Business Verified (also email address confirmed),
- Correct [Endpoint](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/) for the environment in use Sandbox/Live,
- Correct [API Credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/) for the environment in use Sandbox/Live,
- Correct APP-ID

If the issue still persists, I'd recommend to open a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts specifying the API response (with "correlationId" included)

Comment: Additionally, double-check your AppID is granted permissions for the action you're trying to perform. If you're not sure, send it over to us via a ticket and we can double-check it for you.

Comment: PayPal_Federica , Paypal_Roberts it works :) and i havent enough reputaion so i cant able to vote up your answer.

Comment: @PayPal_Federica, how can I check whether my account is verified? As far as I can tell, I am doing all your bullet points right, but still I get the 550001 error.

Comment: @Simone, in order to verify your account you must add a credit card or a bank account into your PayPal account. You can find all the instructions at https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/

Comment: @PayPal_Federica : I have double checked all things but getting only one error message `User is not allowed to perform this action.`